# Connecting Database using c# in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have a problem connecting my database (created in SQL Server 2008 R2 Express) with c# in vs 2013

Here is the code I wrote

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newSchool"].ToString();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
```

the error is `NullReferenceException`

Comment: What is the problem. Do you get an error message? Where is the conn.Open statement?

Comment: What's the error?  What problem are you having?

Comment: And why is everybody using `ConfigurationManager` when you can easily access settings using `Properties.Settings.Default`? (Yes, I'd really like to know).

Comment: NullReferenceException error at the first line

Comment: I'd suggest including the ConnectionStrings section of your config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you define your connection string? In the app.config? Please send us the place where you configure this.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx for help.

See http://www.connectionstrings.com/ how to configure a connection string for .net

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newSchool"].ToString();
```

to...

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newSchool"].ConnectionString;
```

Cheers -

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is no connection string named `newSchool`. It is probably `NewSchool` or some other casing.

---

In response to your comment: You need to provide a proper connection string. The `ConfigurationManager` is used to get a value from the configuration. The `NullReferenceException` shows you that the setting you request is not there.

You need to create a connection string first using the settings manager and then you can access it.

Comment: newSchool is the name of the database

Comment: Well, then you didn't grasp the concept of connection strings. Use the settings manager to create an actual connection string.